# Parse error while running sonar on file that contains Boost_Foreach instruction

Tags: c++, boost, sonarqube, static-analysis

I getting an parse error when I run sonar analysis for file that contains Boost_Foreach instruction

File that contains Boost_Foreach instruction:

```
    BOOST_FOREACH(SExcludedType entry, excludedFiles)
    {
        CString keyName;
        keyName.Format(format, counter);

        CString textRepresentation = SExcludedType::GetStringRepresentation(entry);
        persistentSettings_.SaveNow(const_cast<PTSTR>(keyName.GetString()), textRepresentation);

        ++counter;
    }
```

Parse error:

> 08:18:11.639 ERROR - Unable to parse file: C:\Users\aogonowski\Desktop\Defragler missing files\MainFrame.cpp
>   com.sonar.sslr.api.RecognitionException: Parse error at line 3793 column 1 failed to match all of: RECOVERED_EXPRESSION_STATEMENT STATEMENT
>
> 3787: ::GetStringRepresentation(entry);
>    3788:    persistentSettings_.SaveNow(const_cast(keyName.GetString()), textRepresentation);
>    3789: 
>    3790:    ++counter;
>    3791:   }
>    3792: 
>     -->   }
>
> Failed at rules:
>   /-RECOVERED_EXPRESSION_STATEMENT consumed from (3782, 2) to (3791, 3): ... ) ) , textRepresentation ) ; ++ counter ; }
>   STATEMENT

I was looking for any solution how to set sonnar to analyse that file but I haven't found any solution expect to comment out that problematic code lines.

Comment: What plugin are you running? SonarSource C++ plugin? Community C++ plugin?

Comment: I have both plugins: SonarSource C++ plugin and Community C++ plugin, sholud I turn off one of them?

Comment: Yep. Could you try with the SonarSource C/C++ plugin (latest version is 1.5.2) and switch to the commercial mailing-list?

Comment: I turned off the Community C++ plugin and run the analysis only with the SonarSource C/C++ plugin (latest version is 1.5.2) and there is still that pare error

Comment: Could you please move to the commercial mailing-list and send the full log and complete file? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the property `sonar.cxx.defines` to `BOOST_FOREACH(x,y)` in your Sonar runner config file or pom.xml (whatever you are using).